# What kind of caulk to use on wood that has had deck sealer applied?

Tags: caulk

We have an old buffet that I converted into a vanity for use in the bathroom. To make the top water resistant, we used a deck sealer. Whether or not that was the best choice, the deed is done.

The plumbers we hired cemented the sink to the top of the vanity using a silicone caulk, however, it appears not to have worked. The sink slides freely on the top of the vanity.

What kind of caulk will adhere to the deck-sealed wood?

Comment: what sort of deck sealer did you use? pick something compatible with that.

Comment: Is your "deck sealer" an oil of some sort? Can you share the exact brand & product with us?

Comment: Oh boy. My wife bought and applied it. Unfortunately, I don't think we have the bottle to check, but I'll keep looking.

Comment: Found it. It's Behr Transparent Waterproofing wood finish.

Answer (score 1):

A polyester caulk like [Vulkem](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Vulkem-45-28-7-fl-oz-Limestone-Paintable-Advanced-Sealant-Caulk/3595630?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-pnt-_-ggl-_-LIA_PNT_221_Glue-Adhesives-Caulk-Repair-_-3595630-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=Cj0KCQjwmN2iBhCrARIsAG_G2i6nCUHeTBqFOuijY2ClHQ4_tnG-t9TvMAeacGoW_cd7O9Fb0vLKY1oaAjEcEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) will work. It is totally waterproof and paintable when dry,if that is a need.   It does take a day or 2 to dry because it is not water based. Mineral spirits are needed for clean up, but that is the only bad smell.